# How to find maximum index of a list element if there are duplicates?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
animals = ['Goat', 'Tiger', 'Lion', 'Lion']
```

How can I find the maximum index of `'Lion'`?

```
expected result : 4
```

`'Lion'` is in indices 3 and 4, and I want the maximum index (4).

Comment: reverse the list?

Answer (score 0):

Your index result is wrong, it's not 4 but 3

```py
Animal = ['Goat', 'Tiger', 'Lion','a', 'Lion',1,5,'Lion',3]
Animal = ['Goat', 'Tiger', 'Lion', 'Lion']
def test(list1,word):
    rev_list=list1[::-1]
    idx_rev_list = rev_list.index(word)
    list_len=len(list1)
    res=list_len-idx_rev_list
    return res-1
res=test(Animal,'Lion')
print(res)
print(Animal[res])
```

Comment: Instead you could just do, ``animals.index('<string to find>', -1)``

Comment: It won't work if 'Lion' is in the middle of the list